# The 'AverageRejection' parameter is missing a value

Tags: reporting-services

I have the report that I have build with Reporting Services 2008.

In this report, I have a chart that use throught "strip line" an hidden parameter. The hidden parameter is called "AverageRej". The parameter "AverageReg" is populated by a query. This is the situation:

Configuration hidden parameter
[image]

[image]

[image]

In stripLine I have this code:

```
=iif(IsNothing(Parameters!AverageRejection.Value), 0, Parameters!AverageRejection.Value*100)
```

But, If I try to show a report and the query not have one or more result I have this error:

```
The 'AverageRejection' parameter is missing a value
```

I tried to give a try, I have set AverageRejection as a VisibleParameter, I show a Select box, if I manual setting a null value, I don't have a error message.

What is the error?

Comment: You need to create default value.

Comment: I have modified the second and third tab. I have insert a default value (Null) but the error is the same

Comment: Try to put something in to the label. Change default value to a value; do not use set

Comment: I try to insert in AvailableValues tab, the query. In Default Value tab I have insert a new value with 0 value. But I have the same error

Comment: So what is the name of your parameter? Is it "AverageRej"or "AverageReg" or 'AverageRejection'

Comment: AverageRejection is the correct name.